# Append Json Data in Array of Array(2D Array) in Swift

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, xcode, iosdeployment

```
{
    "status": 200,
    "message": "Success!",
    "result": {
        "LessonDetail": [
            {
                "id": 78,
                "lessonjs": "<script src=\"https://learnspeakthai.com/js/lesson.js\" ></script>",
                "name": "Question words #3: What?",
                "code": "ST1C2L026",
                "chapter_id": "12",
                "sort_order": "25",
                "content_top": "",
                "image": "https://learnspeakthai.com/uploads/images/lesson/lesson_thumb/8b2cbbca4a711009806b915971478cb54b2ab0d1.jpg",
                "show_tone_practice": "0",
                "tone_practice_shown": "None",
                "tone_practise_data": "",
                "show_slideshow": "1",
                "active": "1",
                "created_at": "2011-07-28T02:51:34.000000Z",
                "updated_at": "2014-10-24T20:24:17.000000Z",
                "pdf": "",
                "is_practise_data": 0
            }
        ],
        "SubLesson": [
            {
                "id": 86,
                "name": "Question words 3: What?",
                "show_name": "0",
                "code": "ST1C2L027",
                "lesson_id": "78",
                "sort_order": "5",
                "content_top": "&lsquo;&sup3;A-ry?&rsquo; = &lsquo;what?&rsquo; It is always used at the end of sentence.",
                "slide": [
                    {
                        "id": 321,
                        "sub_lesson_id": "86",
                        "code": "ST1C2L028",
                        "isaana": "&sup3;A-ry",
                        "thai": "อะไร",
                        "english": "What? ",
                        "english_word_order": "",
                        "language_id": "1",
                        "slide": "https://learnspeakthai.com/uploads/images/slide/34322cde0baa04df7ed58295863e390c7a489a98.jpg",
                        "pre_slide": "https://learnspeakthai.com/uploads/images/slide/ff791dbc630a4407eec2d4bdb4cbf677fac820bb.jpg",
                        "audio_en": "https://learnspeakthai.com/uploads/audio/audio_en/ed99dca146d83b40c8a91b1a2cc58844fa9d8162.mp3",
                        "audio_th": "https://learnspeakthai.com/uploads/audio/audio_th/5ca41fb350d2713194b00071fab749d36d376f8c.mp3",
                        "sort_order": null,
                        "pause": "0",
                        "active": "1",
                        "created_at": "2011-07-28T02:55:06.000000Z",
                        "updated_at": "2011-07-28T02:55:21.000000Z",
                        "language_name": "Thai",
                        "language_code": "TH"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 322,
                        "sub_lesson_id": "86",
                        "code": "ST1C2L029",
                        "isaana": "(Kun) c&ordf;heu &sup3;a-ry?",
                        "thai": "คุณชื่ออะไร",
                        "english": "What&rsquo;s your name?",
                        "english_word_order": "(You name what?)",
                        "language_id": "1",
                        "slide": "https://learnspeakthai.com/uploads/images/slide/fff77db9e63b1ed203ef186c1252dee9ee47f1e6.jpg",
                        "pre_slide": "https://learnspeakthai.com/uploads/images/slide/85315f3e7892fdefff80dbc17a140fed7a1a0812.jpg",
                        "audio_en": "https://learnspeakthai.com/uploads/audio/audio_en/158079fe8d6aab8d95201d2c945a378b971a5e04.mp3",
                        "audio_th": "https://learnspeakthai.com/uploads/audio/audio_th/d9f7c4170a13336b95846b995add06f3537e6730.mp3",
                        "sort_order": null,
                        "pause": "0",
                        "active": "1",
                        "created_at": "2011-07-28T02:56:23.000000Z",
                        "updated_at": "2011-08-19T00:20:38.000000Z",
                        "language_name": "Thai",
                        "language_code": "TH"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 323,
                        "sub_lesson_id": "86",
                        "code": "ST1C2L030",
                        "isaana": "C&ordf;heu B&deg;orb",
                        "thai": "ชื่อบ๊อบ",
                        "english": "My name is Bob ",
                        "english_word_order": "(Name Bob)",
                        "language_id": "1",
                        "slide": "https://learnspeakthai.com/uploads/images/slide/783d893e197d718c9d32624cf6aa6eff25113dc2.jpg",
                        "pre_slide": "https://learnspeakthai.com/uploads/images/slide/fae572b408441871d16d9335675f88895c533f4e.jpg",
                        "audio_en": "https://learnspeakthai.com/uploads/audio/audio_en/7b80d533c30f9d7839a1cd5f058c10092960dcf8.mp3",
                        "audio_th": "https://learnspeakthai.com/uploads/audio/audio_th/57ce04c653580cdf525af9b49d8deb19f49c9786.mp3",
                        "sort_order": null,
                        "pause": "0",
                        "active": "1",
                        "created_at": "2011-07-28T02:58:00.000000Z",
                        "updated_at": "2011-07-28T02:58:17.000000Z",
                        "language_name": "Thai",
                        "language_code": "TH"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 324,
                        "sub_lesson_id": "86",
                        "code": "ST1C2L031",
                        "isaana": "An-n&deg;ee r&sect;iak w&sect;ah &sup3;a-ry?",
                        "thai": "อันนี้เรียกว่าอะไร",
                        "english": "What&rsquo;s this called?",
                        "english_word_order": "(This called what?)",
                        "language_id": "1",
                        "slide": "https://learnspeakthai.com/uploads/images/slide/8244e536e5bcd1f0383b322f0df04a31926888f2.jpg",
                        "pre_slide": "https://learnspeakthai.com/uploads/images/slide/0c31968d79a921bf8b2810d8b05b9d01c4f6898f.jpg",
                        "audio_en": "https://learnspeakthai.com/uploads/audio/audio_en/394021ec2ff89c15a607ce3fd31ba0835115b84a.mp3",
                        "audio_th": "https://learnspeakthai.com/uploads/audio/audio_th/9034801d15fb058ea4a2bc0ba545e92cc3ec63a2.mp3",
                        "sort_order": null,
                        "pause": "0",
                        "active": "1",
                        "created_at": "2011-07-28T02:59:24.000000Z",
                        "updated_at": "2011-07-28T03:00:02.000000Z",
                        "language_name": "Thai",
                        "language_code": "TH"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 325,
                        "sub_lesson_id": "86",
                        "code": "ST1C2L032",
                        "isaana": " R&sect;iak w&sect;ah d&sect;ton &deg;my ",
                        "thai": " เรียกว่าต้นไม้ ",
                        "english": "It&rsquo;s called a tree",
                        "english_word_order": "",
                        "language_id": "1",
                        "slide": "https://learnspeakthai.com/uploads/images/slide/2725e831aaf141324cc62dc61300b95dd544d487.jpg",
                        "pre_slide": "https://learnspeakthai.com/uploads/images/slide/b95be383542085e2c3ef1500c86c7c432c8155f9.jpg",
                        "audio_en": "https://learnspeakthai.com/uploads/audio/audio_en/e66433b0437f6b1b6d0f65b61c8b13b4e27fd57d.mp3",
                        "audio_th": "https://learnspeakthai.com/uploads/audio/audio_th/88b3abbec52de4dc667cba0b2fc4db1e1ffc42cb.mp3",
                        "sort_order": null,
                        "pause": "0",
                        "active": "1",
                        "created_at": "2011-07-28T03:01:02.000000Z",
                        "updated_at": "2018-05-15T09:20:24.000000Z",
                        "language_name": "Thai",
                        "language_code": "TH"
                    }
                ],
                "content_bottom": "",
                "image": "",
                "active": "1",
                "created_at": "2011-07-28T02:54:09.000000Z",
                "updated_at": "2011-08-08T03:51:52.000000Z"
            },
            {
                "id": 87,
                "name": "add the polite particle ‘³na’",
                "show_name": "0",
                "code": "ST1C2L033",
                "lesson_id": "78",
                "sort_order": "10",
                "content_top": "For politeness, when you use the word &lsquo;what?&rsquo; on its own you should always add the polite particle &lsquo;&sup3;na&rsquo;. Note: This is a different polite particle than the &lsquo;&deg;na&rsquo; used in conjunction with &lsquo;k&deg;rap&rsquo; / &lsquo;&sect;ka&rsquo;. ",
                "slide": [
                    {
                        "id": 321,
                        "sub_lesson_id": "86",
                        "code": "ST1C2L028",
                        "isaana": "&sup3;A-ry",
                        "thai": "อะไร",
                        "english": "What? ",
                        "english_word_order": "",
                        "language_id": "1",
                        "slide": "https://learnspeakthai.com/uploads/images/slide/34322cde0baa04df7ed58295863e390c7a489a98.jpg",
                        "pre_slide": "https://learnspeakthai.com/uploads/images/slide/ff791dbc630a4407eec2d4bdb4cbf677fac820bb.jpg",
                        "audio_en": "https://learnspeakthai.com/uploads/audio/audio_en/ed99dca146d83b40c8a91b1a2cc58844fa9d8162.mp3",
                        "audio_th": "https://learnspeakthai.com/uploads/audio/audio_th/5ca41fb350d2713194b00071fab749d36d376f8c.mp3",
                        "sort_order": null,
                        "pause": "0",
                        "active": "1",
                        "created_at": "2011-07-28T02:55:06.000000Z",
                        "updated_at": "2011-07-28T02:55:21.000000Z",
                        "language_name": "Thai",
                        "language_code": "TH"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 322,
                        "sub_lesson_id": "86",
                        "code": "ST1C2L029",
                        "isaana": "(Kun) c&ordf;heu &sup3;a-ry?",
                        "thai": "คุณชื่ออะไร",
                        "english": "What&rsquo;s your name?",
                        "english_word_order": "(You name what?)",
                        "language_id": "1",
                        "slide": "https://learnspeakthai.com/uploads/images/slide/fff77db9e63b1ed203ef186c1252dee9ee47f1e6.jpg",
                        "pre_slide": "https://learnspeakthai.com/uploads/images/slide/85315f3e7892fdefff80dbc17a140fed7a1a0812.jpg",
                        "audio_en": "https://learnspeakthai.com/uploads/audio/audio_en/158079fe8d6aab8d95201d2c945a378b971a5e04.mp3",
                        "audio_th": "https://learnspeakthai.com/uploads/audio/audio_th/d9f7c4170a13336b95846b995add06f3537e6730.mp3",
                        "sort_order": null,
                        "pause": "0",
                        "active": "1",
                        "created_at": "2011-07-28T02:56:23.000000Z",
                        "updated_at": "2011-08-19T00:20:38.000000Z",
                        "language_name": "Thai",
                        "language_code": "TH"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 323,
                        "sub_lesson_id": "86",
                        "code": "ST1C2L030",
                        "isaana": "C&ordf;heu B&deg;orb",
                        "thai": "ชื่อบ๊อบ",
                        "english": "My name is Bob ",
                        "english_word_order": "(Name Bob)",
                        "language_id": "1",
                        "slide": "https://learnspeakthai.com/uploads/images/slide/783d893e197d718c9d32624cf6aa6eff25113dc2.jpg",
                        "pre_slide": "https://learnspeakthai.com/uploads/images/slide/fae572b408441871d16d9335675f88895c533f4e.jpg",
                        "audio_en": "https://learnspeakthai.com/uploads/audio/audio_en/7b80d533c30f9d7839a1cd5f058c10092960dcf8.mp3",
                        "audio_th": "https://learnspeakthai.com/uploads/audio/audio_th/57ce04c653580cdf525af9b49d8deb19f49c9786.mp3",
                        "sort_order": null,
                        "pause": "0",
                        "active": "1",
                        "created_at": "2011-07-28T02:58:00.000000Z",
                        "updated_at": "2011-07-28T02:58:17.000000Z",
                        "language_name": "Thai",
                        "language_code": "TH"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 324,
                        "sub_lesson_id": "86",
                        "code": "ST1C2L031",
                        "isaana": "An-n&deg;ee r&sect;iak w&sect;ah &sup3;a-ry?",
                        "thai": "อันนี้เรียกว่าอะไร",
                        "english": "What&rsquo;s this called?",
                        "english_word_order": "(This called what?)",
                        "language_id": "1",
                        "slide": "https://learnspeakthai.com/uploads/images/slide/8244e536e5bcd1f0383b322f0df04a31926888f2.jpg",
                        "pre_slide": "https://learnspeakthai.com/uploads/images/slide/0c31968d79a921bf8b2810d8b05b9d01c4f6898f.jpg",
                        "audio_en": "https://learnspeakthai.com/uploads/audio/audio_en/394021ec2ff89c15a607ce3fd31ba0835115b84a.mp3",
                        "audio_th": "https://learnspeakthai.com/uploads/audio/audio_th/9034801d15fb058ea4a2bc0ba545e92cc3ec63a2.mp3",
                        "sort_order": null,
                        "pause": "0",
                        "active": "1",
                        "created_at": "2011-07-28T02:59:24.000000Z",
                        "updated_at": "2011-07-28T03:00:02.000000Z",
                        "language_name": "Thai",
                        "language_code": "TH"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 325,
                        "sub_lesson_id": "86",
                        "code": "ST1C2L032",
                        "isaana": " R&sect;iak w&sect;ah d&sect;ton &deg;my ",
                        "thai": " เรียกว่าต้นไม้ ",
                        "english": "It&rsquo;s called a tree",
                        "english_word_order": "",
                        "language_id": "1",
                        "slide": "https://learnspeakthai.com/uploads/images/slide/2725e831aaf141324cc62dc61300b95dd544d487.jpg",
                        "pre_slide": "https://learnspeakthai.com/uploads/images/slide/b95be383542085e2c3ef1500c86c7c432c8155f9.jpg",
                        "audio_en": "https://learnspeakthai.com/uploads/audio/audio_en/e66433b0437f6b1b6d0f65b61c8b13b4e27fd57d.mp3",
                        "audio_th": "https://learnspeakthai.com/uploads/audio/audio_th/88b3abbec52de4dc667cba0b2fc4db1e1ffc42cb.mp3",
                        "sort_order": null,
                        "pause": "0",
                        "active": "1",
                        "created_at": "2011-07-28T03:01:02.000000Z",
                        "updated_at": "2018-05-15T09:20:24.000000Z",
                        "language_name": "Thai",
                        "language_code": "TH"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 326,
                        "sub_lesson_id": "87",
                        "code": "ST1C2L033a",
                        "isaana": "&sup3;A-ry &sup3;na?",
                        "thai": "อะไรน่ะ",
                        "english": "What? / pardon?",
                        "english_word_order": "What p.p.? ",
                        "language_id": "1",
                        "slide": "https://learnspeakthai.com/uploads/images/slide/c2e01e9bdc3455275a60fc58640fef574920931a.jpg",
                        "pre_slide": "https://learnspeakthai.com/uploads/images/slide/1c9490fdc1ae25dacdecba8d5054b8bc2e116595.jpg",
                        "audio_en": "https://learnspeakthai.com/uploads/audio/audio_en/c96b08c9ee6afdd3db503abb83dbec673768284b.mp3",
                        "audio_th": "https://learnspeakthai.com/uploads/audio/audio_th/dbfede0423eb13e4fae61f0bfe3f45ef52602868.mp3",
                        "sort_order": null,
                        "pause": "0",
                        "active": "1",
                        "created_at": "2011-07-28T03:04:40.000000Z",
                        "updated_at": "2021-02-16T21:57:32.000000Z",
                        "language_name": "Thai",
                        "language_code": "TH"
                    }
                ],
                "content_bottom": "",
                "image": "",
                "active": "1",
                "created_at": "2011-07-28T03:03:11.000000Z",
                "updated_at": "2021-02-16T21:55:34.000000Z"
            }
        ],
        "GameList": [
            {
                "id": 1189,
                "name": "Question words #1: Matching",
                "code": "ST1C2G001a",
                "chapter_id": "12",
                "lesson_id": "78",
                "content_top": "",
                "game_type": "matching",
                "word_source": "selection_from_all",
                "words_to_display": "10",
                "sort_order": "5",
                "active": "1",
                "is_free": 0,
                "is_subscription": 1,
                "created_at": "2014-10-07T06:38:48.000000Z",
                "updated_at": "2014-10-07T10:25:07.000000Z"
            },
            {
                "id": 1190,
                "name": "Question words #2: Flash card",
                "code": "ST1C2G001b",
                "chapter_id": "12",
                "lesson_id": "78",
                "content_top": "",
                "game_type": "flashcard",
                "word_source": "selection_from_all",
                "words_to_display": "10",
                "sort_order": "6",
                "active": "1",
                "is_free": 0,
                "is_subscription": 1,
                "created_at": "2014-10-07T06:57:22.000000Z",
                "updated_at": "2014-10-07T10:25:38.000000Z"
            }
        ],
        "Slideshow": [
            {
                "id": 321,
                "pre_slide": "https://learnspeakthai.com/uploads/images/slide/ff791dbc630a4407eec2d4bdb4cbf677fac820bb.jpg",
                "slide": "https://learnspeakthai.com/uploads/images/slide/34322cde0baa04df7ed58295863e390c7a489a98.jpg",
                "audio_en": "https://learnspeakthai.com/uploads/audio/audio_en/ed99dca146d83b40c8a91b1a2cc58844fa9d8162.mp3",
                "audio_th": "https://learnspeakthai.com/uploads/audio/audio_th/5ca41fb350d2713194b00071fab749d36d376f8c.mp3"
            },
            {
                "id": 322,
                "pre_slide": "https://learnspeakthai.com/uploads/images/slide/85315f3e7892fdefff80dbc17a140fed7a1a0812.jpg",
                "slide": "https://learnspeakthai.com/uploads/images/slide/fff77db9e63b1ed203ef186c1252dee9ee47f1e6.jpg",
                "audio_en": "https://learnspeakthai.com/uploads/audio/audio_en/158079fe8d6aab8d95201d2c945a378b971a5e04.mp3",
                "audio_th": "https://learnspeakthai.com/uploads/audio/audio_th/d9f7c4170a13336b95846b995add06f3537e6730.mp3"
            },
            {
                "id": 323,
                "pre_slide": "https://learnspeakthai.com/uploads/images/slide/fae572b408441871d16d9335675f88895c533f4e.jpg",
                "slide": "https://learnspeakthai.com/uploads/images/slide/783d893e197d718c9d32624cf6aa6eff25113dc2.jpg",
                "audio_en": "https://learnspeakthai.com/uploads/audio/audio_en/7b80d533c30f9d7839a1cd5f058c10092960dcf8.mp3",
                "audio_th": "https://learnspeakthai.com/uploads/audio/audio_th/57ce04c653580cdf525af9b49d8deb19f49c9786.mp3"
            },
            {
                "id": 324,
                "pre_slide": "https://learnspeakthai.com/uploads/images/slide/0c31968d79a921bf8b2810d8b05b9d01c4f6898f.jpg",
                "slide": "https://learnspeakthai.com/uploads/images/slide/8244e536e5bcd1f0383b322f0df04a31926888f2.jpg",
                "audio_en": "https://learnspeakthai.com/uploads/audio/audio_en/394021ec2ff89c15a607ce3fd31ba0835115b84a.mp3",
                "audio_th": "https://learnspeakthai.com/uploads/audio/audio_th/9034801d15fb058ea4a2bc0ba545e92cc3ec63a2.mp3"
            },
            {
                "id": 325,
                "pre_slide": "https://learnspeakthai.com/uploads/images/slide/b95be383542085e2c3ef1500c86c7c432c8155f9.jpg",
                "slide": "https://learnspeakthai.com/uploads/images/slide/2725e831aaf141324cc62dc61300b95dd544d487.jpg",
                "audio_en": "https://learnspeakthai.com/uploads/audio/audio_en/e66433b0437f6b1b6d0f65b61c8b13b4e27fd57d.mp3",
                "audio_th": "https://learnspeakthai.com/uploads/audio/audio_th/88b3abbec52de4dc667cba0b2fc4db1e1ffc42cb.mp3"
            },
            {
                "id": 326,
                "pre_slide": "https://learnspeakthai.com/uploads/images/slide/1c9490fdc1ae25dacdecba8d5054b8bc2e116595.jpg",
                "slide": "https://learnspeakthai.com/uploads/images/slide/c2e01e9bdc3455275a60fc58640fef574920931a.jpg",
                "audio_en": "https://learnspeakthai.com/uploads/audio/audio_en/c96b08c9ee6afdd3db503abb83dbec673768284b.mp3",
                "audio_th": "https://learnspeakthai.com/uploads/audio/audio_th/dbfede0423eb13e4fae61f0bfe3f45ef52602868.mp3"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

I have created model for json. I want to append value in Array of english key from json.

I am doing --

```
var english_Array = [[String]] ()

guard let subLesson = userResponse.result?.subLesson else {return}

for i in subLesson {
    english_Array.append(i.slide?[0].english ?? "" )
}

print(english_Array)
```

value:

```
[["What?"], ["What?]]
```

I need -

```
[["What?","What&rsquo;s your name?","My name is Bob","What&rsquo;s this called?","It&rsquo;s called a tree"], 
["What?","What&rsquo;s your name?","My name is Bob","What&rsquo;s this called?","It&rsquo;s called a tree","What? / pardon?"]]
```

Comment: Try another for loop inside the one you have now

Comment: It is giving like this --

[["What? "], ["What&rsquo;s your name?"], ["My name is Bob "], ["What&rsquo;s this called?"], ["It&rsquo;s called a tree"], ["What? "], ["What&rsquo;s your name?"], ["My name is Bob "], ["What&rsquo;s this called?"], ["It&rsquo;s called a tree"], ["What? / pardon?"]]

I want like --

 [["What?","What’s your name?","My name is Bob","What’s this called?","It’s called a tree"], ["What?","What’s your name?","My name is Bob","What’s this called?","It’s called a tree","What? / pardon?"]]

Comment: Rather than working with an array of arrays what about using a dictionary, [String: [String]]? Regarding your comment, it looks like you are creating new arrays instead of appending to the existing one(s)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all there are two values for the same key "slide". You should fix it. for now lets consider they are in an array [slide1, slide2] for the key "slides".

```
var english_Array = [[String]] ()
for slide in subLesson.slides {
    let english = slide.map { $0.english ?? "" }
    english_Array.append(english_Array)
}
```

this should do it.